# FFMPEG command suddenly gives error?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, batch, images, merge

Below is my command for FFMPEG to batch merge audio files with an image. It has always worked until today. All of a sudden, it gives me the following error:

```
[NULL @ 00000000004d1440] Unable to find a suitable output format for '@echo'
```

I don't remember making any changes and I can't locate an error either. Below is the command:

```
@echo off

set "sourcedir=G:\Premium Music Club\Prepared_tracks_TEMP"  
set "outputdir=G:\Premium Music Club\Converted_tracks_TEMP" 

PUSHD "%sourcedir%"

for %F in (*.mp3) DO ffmpeg -r 1 -loop 1 -i 1.png -i "%F" -acodec copy -r 1 -shortest "%outputdir%\%~nF.mkv"  

POPD
```

Does anyone have an idea what has been going wrong? Downloading the latest release and searching Google didn't yield any results.

Comment: It looks like a batch file, but you are using single `%F` instead of `%%F`. Also what is the file name and with what encoding did you save it; in what shell do you execute it?

Comment: If you are using the `FOR` command in a batch script (`*.bat` or `*.cmd`) then use doubled _percent sign_ as `%%F` instead of `%F`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've never used a batch file before. I always enter this straight into CMD. %%F gives me the exact same error.

Comment: Regarding file name and encoding: It keeps the original filenames of the audio files. Encoding is unknown to me. How do i check this?

Comment: A temporary solution that is working now is putting for %%F in (*.mp3) DO ffmpeg -r 1 -loop 1 -i 1.png -i "%%F" -acodec copy -r 1 -shortest "%%~nF.mkv" in a batch file and running that. So that part works in isolation

Comment: Please [edit] and update the question with your latest batch file and tell us what the problems remaining are.

Comment: I think i'll keep it this way. I don't have the luxury of pre-set destination and source folders anymore but this is sufficient. Thanks for trying to be of help.